# How to select specific lines and re write it on a single file?

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, dataset

I have a .txt file which contains some data of the voltage, current and radiation lectures of an experiment, and it is displayed as it follows.

I am really new at Python, so I would like to know if there is any function or library that could help me to select only some lines, specifically those where the value displayed in the second row it is positive and higher than let's say, 10, and then re write it on a new file.

Also if you can recommend me any literature to get more into it, I would appreciate it. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use readlines()

```py
with open('file_name','r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines() #this will create a list with each element as a line

with open('file2','w') as f2:
    f2.write(lines[0]) #this will write 1st line to a new file
    f2.writelines(lines) #this will write all the lines in new file
```

Nothing is better than [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) for learning,
If that isn't sufficient [check it out](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/file-handling-python/)